# Should I use Local Web Storage as a Database for a small website?

Tags: javascript, database, authentication, web, local-storage

I am creating a forums website for a roleplay with my friends and not many people are going to use it. But I want to add a feature of user creation, deletion and login/logout.

Should I use Local Web Storage of the browser as a database for that or should I look into other alternatives?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Only feasible if everyone's going to use the same browser on the same computer. Marginally possible, but setting up a server would be much better

Comment: As an alternative to localstorage there's IndexedDB which is worth looking into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Answer (score 0):

No. You should buy an online service, e.g. *AWS Cloud Databases*. And you also need an online web server.

Local storage is unreliable, and easy to lose when cleaning browser caches.

Comment: **Buying** a server is definitely not a necessity. You can always just host something yourself... Either on a Raspi or even directly on the computer... Maybe in a container.

Small projects should **never** cost money.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new and want to experiment, you can try using services like [AWS amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/). You can build full blown website without having to worry about storage or anything. Also you don't have to worry on pricing as it would cost based on the usage and ideally cost nothing as you can use the free tier.